# Rascal: Tree Representation in Repl

Tags: tree, rascal

I understand the default tree representation in the Rascal repl has changed. Following the recipe for the [EXP Combined example](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Languages/Exp/Combined/Manual/Manual.html) I get

```
rascal>import demo::lang::Exp::Combined::Manual::Parse;
ok
rascal>parseExp("2+3*4");
Exp: (Exp) `2+3*4`
```

whereas the documentation says

```
rascal>import demo::lang::Exp::Combined::Manual::Parse;
ok
rascal>parseExp("2+3");
Tree: `2+3`
Tree: appl(prod(sort("Exp"),[sort("Exp"),layouts("Whitespace"), ...
```

Is there a way to get back to this "raw" tree representation (that only language researches will want to see ;-), possibly with layout (indentation etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the underlying tree representation by using `iprintln` from the `IO` library:

```
rascal>import demo::lang::Exp::Combined::Manual::Parse;
ok
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>iprintln(parseExp("2+3*4"))
appl(
  prod(
    sort("Exp"),
    [
      sort("Exp"),
      layouts("Whitespace"),
      lit("+"),
      layouts("Whitespace"),
      sort("Exp")
    ],
    {assoc(left())}),
  [appl(
      prod(
        sort("Exp"),
        [lex("IntegerLiteral")],
        {}),
      [appl(
          prod(
            lex("IntegerLiteral"),
            [iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))],
            {}),
          [appl(
              regular(iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))),
              [char(50)])[
              @loc=|unknown:///|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>)
            ]])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>)
        ]])[
      @loc=|unknown:///|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>)
    ],appl(
      prod(
        layouts("Whitespace"),
        [\iter-star(\char-class([
                range(9,10),
                range(13,13),
                range(32,32)
              ]))],
        {}),
      [appl(
          regular(\iter-star(\char-class([
                  range(9,10),
                  range(13,13),
                  range(32,32)
                ]))),
          [])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(1,0,<1,1>,<1,1>)
        ]])[
      @loc=|unknown:///|(1,0,<1,1>,<1,1>)
    ],appl(
      prod(
        lit("+"),
        [\char-class([range(43,43)])],
        {}),
      [char(43)]),appl(
      prod(
        layouts("Whitespace"),
        [\iter-star(\char-class([
                range(9,10),
                range(13,13),
                range(32,32)
              ]))],
        {}),
      [appl(
          regular(\iter-star(\char-class([
                  range(9,10),
                  range(13,13),
                  range(32,32)
                ]))),
          [])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(2,0,<1,2>,<1,2>)
        ]])[
      @loc=|unknown:///|(2,0,<1,2>,<1,2>)
    ],appl(
      prod(
        sort("Exp"),
        [
          sort("Exp"),
          layouts("Whitespace"),
          lit("*"),
          layouts("Whitespace"),
          sort("Exp")
        ],
        {assoc(left())}),
      [appl(
          prod(
            sort("Exp"),
            [lex("IntegerLiteral")],
            {}),
          [appl(
              prod(
                lex("IntegerLiteral"),
                [iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))],
                {}),
              [appl(
                  regular(iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))),
                  [char(51)])[
                  @loc=|unknown:///|(2,1,<1,2>,<1,3>)
                ]])[
              @loc=|unknown:///|(2,1,<1,2>,<1,3>)
            ]])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(2,1,<1,2>,<1,3>)
        ],appl(
          prod(
            layouts("Whitespace"),
            [\iter-star(\char-class([
                    range(9,10),
                    range(13,13),
                    range(32,32)
                  ]))],
            {}),
          [appl(
              regular(\iter-star(\char-class([
                      range(9,10),
                      range(13,13),
                      range(32,32)
                    ]))),
              [])[
              @loc=|unknown:///|(3,0,<1,3>,<1,3>)
            ]])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(3,0,<1,3>,<1,3>)
        ],appl(
          prod(
            lit("*"),
            [\char-class([range(42,42)])],
            {}),
          [char(42)]),appl(
          prod(
            layouts("Whitespace"),
            [\iter-star(\char-class([
                    range(9,10),
                    range(13,13),
                    range(32,32)
                  ]))],
            {}),
          [appl(
              regular(\iter-star(\char-class([
                      range(9,10),
                      range(13,13),
                      range(32,32)
                    ]))),
              [])[
              @loc=|unknown:///|(4,0,<1,4>,<1,4>)
            ]])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(4,0,<1,4>,<1,4>)
        ],appl(
          prod(
            sort("Exp"),
            [lex("IntegerLiteral")],
            {}),
          [appl(
              prod(
                lex("IntegerLiteral"),
                [iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))],
                {}),
              [appl(
                  regular(iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))),
                  [char(52)])[
                  @loc=|unknown:///|(4,1,<1,4>,<1,5>)
                ]])[
              @loc=|unknown:///|(4,1,<1,4>,<1,5>)
            ]])[
          @loc=|unknown:///|(4,1,<1,4>,<1,5>)
        ]])[
      @loc=|unknown:///|(2,3,<1,2>,<1,5>)
    ]])[
  @loc=|unknown:///|(0,5,<1,0>,<1,5>)
]
ok
```

Comment: I think you can also assign the tree to a variable of type Tree, and then the repl will print tree instead of yielding its leafs.

Comment: That is not correct, you really need `iprintln` for this.

Comment: And use `iprintln(#Exp.definitions)` for the grammar using the same "internal" representation as the tree does for the syntax rules.

Comment: You are basically both right. `iprintln` works, but also assigning the parse result to a (fresh) `Tree` variable will print the raw parse tree, albeit a bit truncated as it ends in `...` before the end of the structure.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to generate a parser for your own bnf format,"all" you have to do is produce the same format as `#Exp` does for the Rascal bnf format, and pass it to the parse function like so: `parse(type(sort("Exp"), definitionsMap))`; the parser generator will eat this "reified" grammar, generate and cache a parser, call this parser and produce a parse tree or throw a parse error.

Comment: Caveat emptor; If the parser generator chokes on an incomplete grammar or so, the error message will be minimally useful.

Comment: The definitions for the tree and production role format can be found in the ParseTree module and the Type module of the standard library. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these things. Most of all I see the BNF parser as a good exercise for me to get into coding Rascal, so maybe I'll try not to be too smart in the first step ;-).
One other thing: I was considering creating a pull request for a Tutor glitch I found. But there doesn't seem to be a Tutor repo on Github. What is your preferred way to receive patches for the Tutor?

Comment: As for the BNF parser: What I really want to achieve is a translator from ANTLR grammars to Rascal code :-) .